Definition of an inner product.
I was solving some problems on isometries on the upper half plane and I came up with the following post:  Excercise in isometries of the half upper plane here the answer states the following inner product as definition:

By definition
$$\langle T'(z)u, T'(z)v\rangle_{T(z)}:=\langle dL_{T(z)^{-1}}(T(z))T'(z)u, dL_{T(z)^{-1}}(T(z))T'(z)v\rangle_e=\dfrac{4T'(z)dz(u)T'(z)d\overline{z}(v)}{(T(z)-\overline{T(z)})^2}=\dfrac{4dz(u)d\overline{z}(v)}{(z-\overline{z})^2}=:\langle u,v\rangle_z$$

My question is, what does this mean, I have never seen such definition and I have been unable to find references to understand it. Thanks for everything :)

It's a Riemannian metric. Concretely, if $u = (u_1,u_2)$ and $v=(v_1,v_2)$ are vectors based at $z=x+iy$, their inner product is$$\frac{u_1v_1+u_2v_2}{y^2}.$$Does that help...?

@AndrewD.Hwang I understand the part of the metric, but I don't understand the first equality, what are the $dL_{T(z)^{-1}}(T(z))T'(z)u$? Thanks a lot

In the linked post it is noted that the space $G$ of all functions $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a Lie group. In a Lie group, we always have for each point $p\in G$ function called left translation by $p$, which is given by
\begin{align*}
L_p:G&\to G, \\
q&\mapsto pq.
\end{align*}
We then say that a Riemannian metric $g$ on $G$ is left-invariant if $L_p$ is an isometry for all $p\in G$, i.e. if
$$g_{pq}(\mathrm{d}(L_p)_q(X_q),\mathrm{d}(L_p)_q(Y_q))=g_q(X_q,Y_q)$$
for all $p,q\in G$ and all $X_q,Y_q\in\mathrm{T}_qG$. The most important thing to notice about left-invariant metrics is that they are completely determined by their action at the neutral element $e$ of the Lie group, as for all $p\in G$ and alla $X_p,Y_p\in\mathrm{T}_pG$ we then have that
$$g_p(X_p,Y_p)=g_e(\mathrm{d}(L_{p^{-1}})(X_p),\mathrm{d}(L_{p^{-1}})(Y_p)).$$
Now in the linked question we can consider equivalently
$$G=\mathbb{H}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\operatorname{Im}(z)>0\}$$
with the group operation given by
$$(a+bi)*(c+di)=a+bc+bdi$$
(to see this, note that our identification is given by $(t\mapsto a+bt)\mapsto a+bi$ and then do the corresponding function composition of the relevant affine functions) and with the left-invariant metric $g$ given by
$$g_z(w_1,w_2)=\frac{1}{\operatorname{Im}(z)^2}\operatorname{Re}(w_1\overline{w_2}).$$
Now the calculation you seem to be trouble by simply boils down to using that the metric is left-invariant, as we then have that
\begin{align*}
g_{T(z)}(T'(z)u,T'(z)v)
&=g_{T(z)^{-1}*T(z)}(\mathrm{d}(L_{T(z)^{-1}})_{T(z)}(T'(z)u),\mathrm{d}(L_{T(z)^{-1}})_{T(z)}(T'(z)v)) \\
&=g_{e}(\mathrm{d}(L_{T(z)^{-1}})_{T(z)}(T'(z)u),\mathrm{d}(L_{T(z)^{-1}})_{T(z)}(T'(z)v)).
\end{align*}
where it is important to note that $T(z)^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $T(z)$ with respect to the group operation $*$ and is not the evaluation $T^{-1}(z)$ of the inverse function. To finish off from here it is just a matter of determining explicitly the differential of the left-translation (I'll leave that out as it did not seem to be what you were asking about). Hopefully this helps!
